# Can anyone please give me the step by step installation process of the oracle development suite 10g on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: sql, oracle, ubuntu, oracleforms, developer-tools

I already have oracle 11g Enterprise Edition installed on my machine. But now I have to work with Reports and Forms Builder for which it was told to install the Oracle Developer Suite 10g.

I have downloaded the `.cpio` files from the oracle site
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/developer-suite/downloads/101202linuxsoft-099233.html

Now what should I do with these files?
Thank You.

Comment: Who told you to install 10g Developer Suite? Why not ask them to help you? Also, why 10g and not 11g, 12c?

Comment: I asked them. But they are working on windows and don't seem to know about how to install it in ubuntu.

Comment: Any version is fine for me. I think i just need to find a way to somehow work on the Forms and Reports builder on Ubuntu cause i dont want to install Windows again. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle 10g2? Wow that's kind of oldish, but here it is:

1. Install libaio1 library:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update; 
   sudo apt-get install -y libaio1 bc
   ```
2. Download [from Oracle] and install the oracle database package. Make sure you get the correct architecture (takes around 3 minutes on a slow machine):

   ```
   sudo dpkg -i oracle-xe-universal_10.2.0.1-1.0_i386.deb
   ```
3. Configure Oracle [change password as needed] (takes around 4 minutes on a slow machine):

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
   ```

   and respond to each question:

   ```
   Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Configuration
   -------------------------------------------------
   This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 10g Express 
   Edition.  The following questions will determine whether the database should 
   be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that 
   will be used for database accounts.  Press <Enter> to accept the defaults. 
   Ctrl-C will abort.

   Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]: <Enter>

   Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]: <Enter>

   Specify a password to be used for database accounts.  Note that the same
   password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM.  Oracle recommends the use of 
   different passwords for each database account.  This can be done after 
   initial configuration: system
   Confirm the password: system

   Do you want Oracle Database 10g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]: <Enter>

   Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
   Configuring Database...Done
   Starting Oracle Database 10g Express Edition Instance...Done
   Installation Completed Successfully.
   To access the Database Home Page go to "http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex"
   ```
4. Set up session environment variables in ~/.bashrc:

   ```
   # =====================
   # Oracle database setup
   # =====================

   export ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server
   export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
   export ORACLE_SID=XE
   ```
5. Logout and login again, to load the changes.

Comment: I am actually having a doubt on this. Its actually like I already have oracle 11g Enterprise Edition installed on my machine. But now its like I have to work on this Reports and Forms Builder for which it was told to install the Oracle Devleoper Suite 10g. What am I supposed to do? Thank You.

Comment: @TheImpaler - the OP's question is not as clear as we might like but they are asking about installing Forms and Reports Builder not the database.

Comment: Yes it is for installing the Forms and Reports Builder in Ubuntu 16.04. I already have  the oracle database 11g installed on my machine and I also installed the sql developer. Now I want to install the Forms and Reports Builder. We were told to install the Oracle Development Suite 10g for this. I don't know like how to do this in Ubuntu. Please help me ASAP.

Comment: @APC Sorry, I misunderstood.